# 2D rotation of rectangular array in C

Tags: c, rotation, 2d, transform

I was experimenting around with 2d array manipulation in c. in-place rotation of a 2d shape in particular, so i did my research and came up with :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define RAD(x) ((x) * 3.14 / 180)

char shape[3][3] = {{1, 1, 1},
                    {1, 0, 1},
                    {1, 1, 1}};

char nf[5][5]= {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
               {0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
               {0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
               {0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
               {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};

char expa[5][5]= {{0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
                  {0, 1, 0, 1, 0},
                  {1, 0, 0, 0, 1},
                  {0, 1, 0, 1, 0},
                  {0, 0, 1, 0, 0}};

void print(int row, int col, char shapein[][col]) {
  for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < col; ++j) {
      printf("%c", ((shapein[i][j]) == 1) ? '#' : ' ');
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}

void main() {
  int nw = 5;
  int nh = 5;

  int xf = nw / 2;
  int yf = nh / 2;
  float angle = RAD(90);


  for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
      int nx = ((i - xf) * cos(angle) - (j - yf) * sin(angle)) + xf;
      int ny = ((i - xf) * sin(angle) + (j - yf) * cos(angle)) + yf;

      nf[nx][ny] = shape[i][j];
    }
  }

  print(5, 5, nf);
}
```

i was expecting to get output like this :

[image: OK output]

however what i get is :

[image: Wrong output]

i did what i understood from my research:
 - rotations do happen at origin (assuming top left corner)
 - moved coords so that it is in origin scale.
 - used output array's dimension as space when rotating.

I am stumped, i need a little help.
while at it, as you can see from my code, i hard coded the new rotated dimensions,
however, it would be nice if somebody could guide me how to calculate new rotated dimensions dynamically,without using the "maximum of corners" method.

Comment: You are literallly rotating by angle to get the indices?

Comment: Yes, I pegged the indexes as coordinates

Answer (score 1):

1. The expected result you show looks like `shape` rotated by 45º, but you set the angle to 90º.
2. You are working with integer coordinates but using floating-point functions. The `sin` and `cos` routines necessarily return approximations, and, when floating-point values are converted to integers, they are truncated. You may prefer rounding, perhaps using the `round` function.
3. `xf` and `yf` appear to be set to the center of the image using `nw / 2` and `nh / 2`, but they are integers, so the result, 2 in each case, is a considerable distance from the actual center, 2.5.

There are likely additional errors, but you should fix those and continue working. Also, take steps to debug your code. Inside the loop, print each value of `xf`, `yf`, `nx`, and `ny` so you can see the inputs and outputs of the calculations. Check them manually to see if they are right or not. If they are not right, examine the individual calculations to see what they are doing.

Comment: And btw sin(90) == 1 and cos(90) == 0 which simplifies the code a lot ... (actually (very) likely to give a little less than 1, due to PI and sin inaccuracy, and on such low (integer) indexes the result will likely be not good!)